# Change permissions on single file in tar.gz file

Tags: linux, windows, file-permissions, tar, mingw

I need to change permission on a single file in a tar.gz archive without extracting it, but I was unable to find any way to achieve it either on man pages or by google search.

More detailed scenario:

We start on a Linux machine with three files:

```
[root@localhost tar-test]# ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Nov 17 14:41 a.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root 0 Nov 17 14:41 b.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Nov 17 14:41 c.txt
```

Then we create tar.gz archive:

```
tar cvzf test.tar.gz a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

Then, test.tar.gz is sent to my Windows machine. Now I need to change permissions of a.txt file without extracting the whole archive. I have access to MinGW, but not to a full Linux machine (virtual or physical). I also don't want to extract the whole archive. It can be assumed, that I know both name and location of the file in the archive.

The solution is restricted to command line tools, since I intend to script it later on.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, couldn't you change the file permission on linux before you compress it?

Comment: Long story short, I have no control over Linux part of the process.

Comment: Have you tried extracting the single file, updating its permissions and updating the archive? Not that this will necessarily be any faster or disc-intensive than extracting the full archive. The problem with zipped files is that changing a single bit will completely change the archive from the point where the change is encoded. The best you could hope to do is to `gunzip` the uncompressed `.tar` file, patch that and `gzip` it again, but you'll need to find the detailed `tar` format in order to patch the correct check-sums.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, but since it is extracted onto Windows-controlled storage, all information about permissions is lost and invoking `chmod` doesn't change anything. I hoped that there is some combination of options in `tar` which would allow me to solve the problem, and it's just that I missed it during my search.

Answer (score 0):

I was just faced with the same question and came up with this using Python:

```python
import os, tarfile


def chmod_in_targz(archivepath:str, files_to_change:list[str], new_mode:int):
    os.rename(archivepath, f"{archivepath}.orig")
    with tarfile.open(f"{archivepath}.orig", "r:gz") as source:
        with tarfile.open(archivepath, "w:gz") as target:
            for entry in source.getmembers():
                if entry.path in files_to_change:
                    entry.mode = new_mode # <-- HERE WE CHANGE THE PERMISSION
                target.addfile(entry, source.extractfile(entry))

    os.remove(f"{archivepath}.orig")


cwd = os.path.dirname(__file__)

chmod_in_targz("test.tar.gz", ["a.txt"], 0o666)
```

Running this will:

1. rename `test.tar.gz` to `test.tar.gz.orig`
2. create a new `test.tar.gz` based on the content of `test.tar.gz.orig` but with fixed file permissions
3. delete `test.tar.gz.orig`